# Jquery : How to detect when text is on a rotated div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time understanding the formula to detect if a text is on a rotated shape, the formula I use right now is similar to the image below:

[image]

There's now a new variable which is the angle, here's the code :

https://jsfiddle.net/b62bkthk/2/

```js
onornot(); 

function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
    var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
    obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
    obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
    obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
    obj.css("transform");
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }

    if(angle < 0) angle +=360;
    return angle;
}

function onornot() {
  $(".text").each(function() {
    var self_text = $(this),
        self_textLeft = self_text.position().left,
        self_textTop = self_text.position().top,
        self_textWidth = self_text.width(),
        self_textHeight = self_text.height();
      
    $(".shape, .background").each(function() {
      var self_shape = $(this),
        self_shapeLeft = self_shape.position().left,
        self_shapeTop = self_shape.position().top,
        self_shapeWidth = self_shape.width(),
        self_shapeHeight = self_shape.height();
       var angle = getRotationDegrees($(this));
        
      if((self_textLeft + self_textWidth) > self_shapeLeft && self_textLeft < (self_shapeLeft + self_shapeWidth) && (self_textTop + self_textHeight) > self_shapeTop && self_textTop < (self_shapeTop + self_shapeHeight)){
       alert(self_text.attr('id') + ' is on ' + self_shape.attr('id'));
     } else {
       alert(self_text.attr('id') + ' is NOT on ' + self_shape.attr('id'));
     }

    });
  });
}
```

```css
.elements,
.element {
  position: absolute
}

#s1 {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}

#t1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
}

#s2 {
  background: #333333;
  top: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

#t2 {
  top: 161px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

#t3 {
  top: 100px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout" style="position:relative; margin-top:30px; margin-left:50px;">
<div class="elements">
  <div id="s1" class="element background"></div>
  <div id="t1" class="element text" style="color:red;">text</div>
  <div id="s2" class="element shape"></div>
  <div id="t2" class="element text" style="color:red;">text invert</div>
  <div id="t3" class="element text" style="color:red;">text3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, some texts are on the rotated shape but the alert box says that it is NOT on. What would the new formula look like ?